# make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, android, static, android-asynctask

i have a code in which i make an http request in an AsyncTask

```
public class Sendcolorvalue extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //do your work here
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.102/HR/index.php?command=" + command);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
           // do something with data here-display it or send to mainactivity
    }

}
```

What i want is to execute it from a menu item selected event so i type:

```
Sendcolorvalue.execute();
```

and an error appears :

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method execute(String...) from the type AsyncTask

Comment: I'm confused. Why not just create an instance of Sendcolorvalue and call `execute()` on that instance?

Comment: You need an instance to call that method.

Comment: please show me how to do that i am veeery new in android development

Comment: @Chris: This is nuts and bolts basic Java and shows that you are doing things in the wrong order. You will want to first take a basic Java tutorial before trying to code Android. You can't stumble through this and hope to succeed, but instead will want to prepare yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your class by doing this:

Sendcolorvalue scv = new Sendcolorvalue();

You can now execute the code by calling the methods you hava made.
For example:

scv.myMethod();

Comment: That's `AsyncTask`. You don't call the implemented or overridden method, you call `.execute(somestringOrUrl)`. The methods he overrides will be called by the `AsyncTask` class before the work is done in background (`onPreExecute'), during the task (`doInBackground`) and after the work is done (`onPostExecute`), where the first and last one is executed on the main thread, while `doInBackground` is executed in a different thread. `AsyncTask` just makes it easier to handle such situations

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to access that method is, as you can read from the exception a "static" way, this means that you are considering like if there is only one "copy" of that class running in your system.
This is very difficult due to the fact that is a "task" (AsyncTask) so is possible that you will need more instance of that class, in few word more than one "copy" of that class.

Each task will be executed separately from the others, so you have to call its own method "execute".

How to tell the JVM all this?

```
Sendcolorvalue sender = new Sendcolorvalue(params);
sender.execute();
```

Mind that if you do this:

```
Sendcolorvalue sender = new Sendcolorvalue(params);
Sendcolorvalue secondsender = new Sendcolorvalue(params);
sender.execute();
```

Only the first of the two sender will be active.

If you use something like:

```
Sendcolorvalue.execute();
```

(that I remember you is not possible because there isn't a static execute method)
You are creating a logic issue.

I suggest you to read something about static and instantiating classes.